# How do I send a parameter to the lead convert page for Opportunity Name field. IN LIGHTNING!

Tags: custom-button, lightning-experience, leads, lead-conversion, parameters

IN LIGHTNING EXPERIENCE:
I want to pass the Opportunity Name as a parameter to the Standard Lead Convert Form, so that users can just deal with the Account creation and press save, if they leave the Opportunity Name field Blank an Opportunity does not get created, and this is not ideal.

How do I pass a parameter to auto fill in the Opportunity Name field?
And should it be via a Button or Action?